# Cannot see error message in http response in Kotlin Fuel

Tags: http, elasticsearch, kotlin, fuel

I am sending an HTTP PUT request to my Elasticsearch server using Fuel library on Kotlin. However, I cannot see an error body if the server returns 404 or 400. I am expecting to get an error message similar to the following:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "invalid_snapshot_name_exception",
        "reason": "[snap1:kopya3]Invalid snapshot name [kopya3], snapshot with the same name already exists"
      }
    ],
    "type": "invalid_snapshot_name_exception",
    "reason": "[snap1:kopya3]Invalid snapshot name [kopya3], snapshot with the same name already exists"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Here's my code:

```
        val (request, response, result) = fullUrl
            .httpPut()
            .body(payload)
            .responseString()

        val (bytes, error) = result

        print(error)
```

Instead what I see is:

```
HTTP Exception 400 Bad Request
    com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.FuelError$Companion.wrap(FuelError.kt:84)
    com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt.response(Deserializable.kt:168)
    com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.requests.DefaultRequest.responseString(DefaultRequest.kt:475)
    com.a.b.c.d.model.Cluster.createSnapshot(Cluster.kt:67)
    com.a.b.c.d.model.Cluster.createSnapshot$default(Cluster.kt:57)
    com.a.b.c.d.model.ClusterKt.main(Cluster.kt:85)
Caused by: HTTP Exception 400 Bad Request
    com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.FuelError$Companion.wrap(FuelError.kt:86)
Caused by: com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.HttpException: HTTP Exception 400 Bad Request
    com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.requests.RequestTask.prepareResponse(RequestTask.kt:35)
    com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.requests.RequestTask.call(RequestTask.kt:47)
    com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.requests.RequestTask.call(RequestTask.kt:14)
    com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.DeserializableKt.response(Deserializable.kt:166)
    com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.requests.DefaultRequest.responseString(DefaultRequest.kt:475)
    com.a.b.c.d.model.Cluster.createSnapshot(Cluster.kt:67)
    com.a.b.c.d.model.Cluster.createSnapshot$default(Cluster.kt:57)
    com.a.b.c.d.model.ClusterKt.main(Cluster.kt:85)
```

How can I see the actual error message? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem by looking at `response.data` which is a bytes array. Converting it to string by `String(response.data)` I could see the error message.

Answer (score 0):

It's really quite annoying that the default exception doesn't just print this.

I struggled with the generics on this one to pull the handler into its own function, so I thought I share my complete code here.

```kotlin
    fun <T> genericErrorHandler(response: Response, result: Result.Failure<Exception>): T {
        println("Request to url ${response.url} failed, server returned:")
        println(String(response.data))
        throw result.getException()
    }

    private fun someRequest(url: String, jsonBody: String): SomeDataFormatYouExpectOnSuccess {
        val (_, response, result) = url.httpPost().header("Content-Type", "application/json; utf-8")
            .header("Authorization", "") // adding some headers
            .jsonBody(jsonBody)
            .responseString()
        return when (result) {
            is Result.Failure -> genericErrorHandler(response, result)
            is Result.Success -> {
                val data = result.get()
                gson.fromJson(data, SomeDataFormatYouExpectOnSuccess::class.java)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm dumbfounded by the fact that Fuel doesn't throw an exception if it can't reach the host... or for anything else. This whole notion of "Result" looks like C and totally ignores that exception handling is a major reason most applications were moved from C to... pretty much any other language.